# Password required to access private key in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a certificate with private key installed in my certificate store.  It required the password in order to install it, which I provided.  My question is whether or not I need to provide it again when referencing it in code.  I need to "sign" a SAML2 request using the private key.  Do I need to use an overload of `X509Certificate2()` that takes in the password in order for the code to allow me to access the private key for signing?  It was questionable to me since I already had to provide it upon installation of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

My sources tell me no. =)

Once you have installed it in the windows keystore, the private key is usable to all the applications running as the user.

There is an option which you can use called "Enable strong private key protection". Password would then be prompted at every use.

The overloaded version X509Certificate2() constructor is used to read a raw p12 file, in the case you don't use the keystore. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148417.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I may need to create a new question but when I look at the certificate in the store, I see the message "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate", however when I access it within code, the private key is null.